# Android: How to implement seek bar on top of current activity on a button press

Tags: android

Suppose we have an activity running with two buttons(b1,b2(to show seekbar)) and an imageview . the imageview is covering 80% of the screen . and 20% the buttons. There is no room to add a seek bar .

So i want to ask is there a way to show a seek bar on top of the current activity(image view and buttons) , when b2 is clicked.

I want a popup like layout .when button b2 is clicked a popup type layout appears having a seekbar in it , like in some music apps , when we click the sound button , the sound seek bar pops up , and disappears after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can disappears dialog by using Handler class and by using dialog.setOnDismissListener